# How long did Ahashverosh stop the construction of the temple before Koresh?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, purim

[What happened to King Achashverosh?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138216/what-happened-to-king-achashverosh)

Here they say that he stopped the temple from being built.

How long did he stop it for? Before Koresh started it

Thx

Comment: @RabbiKaii yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Rashi, **eighteen years**.

According to [Ezra 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.4.1), it was Cyrus ([Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi%20on%20Ezra%204:7:1)<sup>1</sup>) himself who quickly halted the construction after starting it ([Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi%20on%20Ezra%204:5:2)<sup>2</sup> - this was still in his first year as King), and Achashverosh simply upheld it. From the get go, the Samaritans and co. had been pressuring Israel to not build it, and ended up writing to Cyrus and convincing him to put a halt to things.

According to [this Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi%20on%20Ezra%204:24:1)<sup>3</sup> then, the construction was halted from the first year of Cyrus to the second year of Darius; eighteen years:

> באדין. אז היתה בטלה מלאכת בנין בית אלהים אשר בירושלים עד שנת שתים
> לדריוש מלך פרס שאחר כורש מלך אחשורוש שלקח אסתר ואחר אחשורוש מלך דריוש
> בנו של אחשורוש שהוא בן אסתר ומשנת אחת לכורש מלך פרס עד שנת שתים לדריוש
> **י"ח שנה** שהשלימו שבעים שנה לחרבות ירושלים
>
> Then the work of the building of the House of God, which was in
> Jerusalem, was suspended until the second year of Darius, the king of
> Persia; for after Cyrus, Ahasuerus, who married Esther, reigned, and
> after Ahasuerus, Darius, the son of Ahasuerus, who was the son of
> Esther, reigned. And from the first year of Cyrus, the king of Persia,
> until the second year of Darius were **eighteen years**, which completed
> the seventy years from the destruction of Jerusalem.

---

<sup>1. Ezra 4:7 ad loc

2. Ezra 4:5 ad loc, 2

3. Ezra 4:24 ad loc</sup>