# Achashverosh earned Olam Haba?

Tags: sources-mekorot, purim

In Let My Nation Live by Yosef Deutsch, p358, [he claims](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138216/what-happened-to-king-achashverosh/138218#138218) that Achashverosh earned Olam Haba.

There is no footnote on that paragraph, but the preceding paragraph's footnote lists `Rokeach; Yedei Moshe; R' Shmuel di Uzidah; Yad Hamelech`. The next paragraph's footnote lists `Shekalim, ch. 5; see Gra; Tzemach David to Seder Olam 29; see Rashi to Megilla 11b; Targum Rishon 1:1; Eshkol Hakofer`.

I haven't been able to look up all of these, and none of the ones I had access to (mainly the Gra and Rashi mentions) state that he earned Olam Haba. However, I was just wondering if anyone could confirm the source, and, for bonus, explain how it taitches with the vort "*Achashverosh hu Achashverosh - he was the same before and after the events of Purim*."

Comment: The footnotes are going on separate points? The first referring to how Mordechai was less popular amongst the less righteous Jews who he rebuked / those who were jealous of his wealth and power. The second batch are talking about when Daryaveish became king, Mordechai resigned and would eventually have a role in preparing the bird offering in the Beis Hamikdash - its nothing to do with Achashveirosh at all?

Comment: @Dov do you know that from looking them up, or from assuming that they are only talking about what their own paragraph mentions?

Comment: I saw a few and no mention of olam habah

Comment: Maybe because he's off this list https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.2?lang=he&with=all. Though the meforshim explain that the Mishna only mentions wise people who you might think would get olam haba anyway

Comment: פוקד עוון אבות על בנים